# How to determine if a signed in user is a teacher in google classroom?

Tags: google-classroom

For the app I am building for elementary schools, teachers can access it by logging into their classroom account, but students cannot. How do I determine if a particular user is a teacher?

I noticed that the test teacher account has the permission CREATE_COURSE, but the student does not. Can I assume that is universally true... that if someone has a CREATE_COURSE permission, they are a teacher for some course.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned above, if you send request to [userProfiles](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles), with userId, if in the response you get permissions as create_course, then its teacher. Other wise its student.

```
{
 "id": string,
 "name": {
 object(Name)
},
"emailAddress": string,
"photoUrl": string,
"permissions": [
{
  object(GlobalPermission)// Here it should be create_course for teacher
 }
],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach here is [list courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list?hl=es) with the query parameter: 'teacherId' => 'me'. That way you get all the courses the current user is teaching. If you get 0 results, it means the user is not a teacher anywhere. Anyway, if you just need to know if the user is considered a teacher, it might be more efficient the other way around.

Comment: Since the next step was getting the courses for the teacher, this might work better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguishing teachers from students via the `CREATE_COURSE` permission may be sufficient for your use case, but note that depending on how the domain's instance of Classroom has been configured, users may be able to self-identify as teachers; see https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6071551.

Answer (score 1):

Just recently, according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760055, you may use https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles to determine whether the user is teacher

```
{
  "verifiedTeacher": boolean
}
```