# Feature request -- add teacher or student role to userProfile

Tags: google-classroom

I'm currently using the below to determine if a classroom user is a teacher or a student, with the requisite implementations of classroom_user_profile and classroom_courses.

Is there a more straightforward way to ask this question of the API? or would it be possible to augment the user profile with an identifier that discriminates between teacher & student roles.

Best,

Sean

```
  def is_teacher? client
    profile = classroom_user_profile(client)
    has_courses = classroom_courses(client, only_me:true).size != 0
    can_create_courses = profile.has_key?('permissions') and profile['permissions'].find{ |h| h.has_value?('CREATE_COURSE') } != nil
    is_teacher = can_create_courses || has_courses
  end
```

Comment: I feel sending the request to Userprofiles(https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles) with userid and in the response if you get "create_course" as permission, then its teacher. However, there are some other solutions mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830670/how-to-determine-if-a-signed-in-user-is-a-teacher-in-google-classroom/32850650#32850650 which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's something we've thought about, but we don't provide it because in Google Classroom the same person can be a teacher of one course and a student in another. For example, a college student could be taking some courses and TA'ing others. The role of teacher or student is really only relevant within a given course, and that is where the API exposes it.